# Mavericks Mail- Sent folder not updating

Tags: mail.app, macos

Ever since my upgrade to Mavericks my sent mail folder has not logged any of the messages I have sent. Any idea how to get it to refresh and find the messages I have sent?

Comment: When I logged into my mail (we use exchange) through the website, none of the mail I had sent since the upgrade showed in the sent folders there either.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well after upgrading to Mavericks. The solution for me was to select a different Outgoing Mail Server. My Exchange account was set to use the "Exchange SMTP" server (which worked fine for me prior to Mavericks). The other option in the pull down menu was something called "USERNAME@SERVERNAME (Exchange)" so I picked it. This solved the problem. Sent mail once again appears in my Exchange Sent Mail folder.

The weird thing is that this option is not listed as one of the SMTP servers if I click on "Edit SMTP server list".  Maybe it's something other than SMTP?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. To choose the Exchange protocol instead of the SMTP solved the issues of not stored mails. The problem is that the Exchange protocol (maybe only in my case) has other issues, i.e. size restriction. Therefore i have to rely on SMTP protocol.
btw: that the exchange options does not appear in the smtp server list is logical as it is a fixed communication procedure and has not to be configured like SMTP. By using the Exchange protocol the Exchange server stores the sent mails in the right folder with SMTP protocol all is up to client. And exactly here the problem seems to be in mavericks or its mail client.